# Sitecore JSS not working with Pinia/Vuex

Tags: jss

I am having issues trying to integrated `Pinia@2.0.14` with Sitecore JSS App built from version `15.0.2`. The sample app uses `"vue": "~2.6.10"`. When I am running the app locally in connect mode using `jss start:connected`, everything works fine but when I deploy it to sitecore server using jss build. It is giving me following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
   at Module.f140 (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist\RACQForms\server.bundle.js:51544:52)
   at __webpack_require__ (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist\RACQForms\server.bundle.js:20:30)
   at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist\RACQForms\server.bundle.js:84:18
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist\RACQForms\server.bundle.js:87:10)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
Description: An unhandled exception occurred.

Exception Details: Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Object(...) is not a function
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
   at Module.f140 (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist\RACQForms\server.bundle.js:51544:52)
   at __webpack_require__ (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist\RACQForms\server.bundle.js:20:30)
   at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist\RACQForms\server.bundle.js:84:18
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\dist\RACQForms\server.bundle.js:87:10)
   at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
   at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
   at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
   at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
   at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
```

I am assuming it might be related to version of Node being out of date. I have node version `node-v12.22.12-x64.msi` on sitecore servers.

Vue.config.js file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let vueConfig = {};

if (process.env.BUILD_TARGET_ENV === 'server') {
  const serverConfig = require('./server/server.vue.config');
  vueConfig = serverConfig;
} else if (process.env.BUILD_TARGET_ENV === 'client') {
  // We can't directly assign a value to `process.env.BASE_URL`, as it is always assigned by `config.publicPath`, regardless of whether `config.publicPath` is defined or undefined.
  // Therefore, we set a value for `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` then use that value for `config.publicPath`.
  vueConfig.publicPath = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

  // By default, Vue cli uses HtmlWebpackPlugin to generate the html file used for rendering the app.
  // When in production mode, it also enables the HtmlWebpackPlugin `minify` option and sets
  // the `removeAttributeQuotes` option of the html minifier to true.
  // Our server-side rendering script uses string replacement to determine where to inject the
  // rendered output of the JSS app. For example, the SSR script is looking for `<div id="root">` and injecting
  // the rendered output into that place in the html template string.
  // However, with the `removeAttributeQuotes` enabled, our html template output is `<div id=root>`, so the SSR
  // string replacement can't find `<div id="root">`.
  // Therefore, by disabling the `removeAttributeQuotes` flag for html minification, all is well.
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    vueConfig.chainWebpack = (config) => {
      config.plugin('html').init((Plugin, args) => {
        const newArgs = {
          ...args[0],
        };
        newArgs.minify.removeAttributeQuotes = false;
        return new Plugin(newArgs);
      });
    };
  }
} else {
  vueConfig.devServer = {
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
    proxy: `http://localhost:${process.env.PROXY_PORT || 3042}`,
    https: true,
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('./certs/localhost.pfx'),
    pfxPassphrase: "arun1234",
    headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
  };
}

// We may already have an existing `configureWebpack` definition (e.g. when building the server bundle).
// So we need to preserve that definition and ensure it is invoked along with the config
// options that are common to both client/server bundles.
const existingConfigureWebpack = vueConfig.configureWebpack;

vueConfig.configureWebpack = (config) => {
  if (existingConfigureWebpack) {
    existingConfigureWebpack(config);
  }

  // we turn off `.mjs` file support in Vue, because `graphql` ships
  // mjs files in its npm package (bad) and Vue's webpack settings destroy
  // graphql's mjs files, causing strange runtime errors. By disabling mjs,
  // we make webpack use the .js files in graphql instead, which work fine.
  const indexOfMjs = config.resolve.extensions.indexOf('.mjs');
  if (indexOfMjs > -1) {
    config.resolve.extensions.splice(indexOfMjs, 1);
  }

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
  },
  {
    test: /\.mjs$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    type: "javascript/auto"
  });

};
vueConfig.css = {
  loaderOptions: {
    sass: {
      additionalData: `
        @import "@/assets/css/_variables.scss";
        @import "@/assets/css/utilities/_mixins.scss";
      `
    }
  }
};
// Below is a workaround when building the app within the context of the JSS monorepo.
// The monorepo uses symlinks within the `node_modules` folder to reference `sitecore-jss-*` packages,
// which causes the eslint loader to attempt resolving eslint config from the _actual_ package location,
// not the "virtual" location under `node_modules`. In turn, an incorrect eslint config is resolved and
// breaks the build process.
// The workaround is to exclude the `packages/sitecore-jss*` packages from eslint-loader.

// We may already have an existing `chainWebpack` definition (e.g. when building the server bundle).
// So we need to preserve that definition and ensure it is invoked along with the config
// options that are common to both client/server bundles.
const existingChainWebpack = vueConfig.chainWebpack;
vueConfig.chainWebpack = (config) => {
  if (existingChainWebpack) {
    existingChainWebpack(config);
  }
  config.module.rule('eslint').exclude.add(/packages(\\|\/)sitecore-jss*/);
};

module.exports = vueConfig;
```

Create APP.js

```
Vue.use(Meta);
Vue.use(SitecoreJssStorePlugin);
Vue.use(SitecoreJssPlaceholderPlugin, { componentFactory });
Vue.use(VueApollo);
Vue.use(PiniaVuePlugin);
const pinia = createPinia();
Vue.component('RacqSelectFormulateInput', RacqSelectFormulateInput)
Vue.use(VueFormulate,  {
  classes: {
    outer: 'forms-input-wrapper',
  },
  library: {
    selectbox: {
      classification: 'select',
      component: 'RacqSelectFormulateInput'
    }
  }
});
Vue.use(pinia)

// createApp is invoked by both the main and SSR entry points, so the two entry points can use the same app creation process.
export function createApp(initialState, i18n) {
  Vue.config.productionTip = false;

  const router = createRouter();
  const graphQLProvider = createGraphQLProvider(initialState);

  const vueOptions = {
    apolloProvider: graphQLProvider,
    router,

    render: (createElement) => createElement(AppRoot),
  };
  // conditionally add i18n to the Vue instance if it is defined
  if (i18n) {
    vueOptions.i18n = i18n;
  }
  vueOptions.pinia = pinia;
  const app = new Vue(vueOptions);

  // if there is an initial state defined, push it into the store, where it can be referenced by interested components.
  if (initialState) {
    app.$jss.store.setSitecoreData(initialState);
  }

  return { app, router, graphQLProvider };
}
import Vue from 'vue';
import Meta from 'vue-meta';
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo';
import { SitecoreJssPlaceholderPlugin } from '@sitecore-jss/sitecore-jss-vue';
import AppRoot from './AppRoot';
import { createRouter } from './router';
import SitecoreJssStorePlugin from './lib/SitecoreJssStorePlugin';
import GraphQLClientFactory from './lib/GraphQLClientFactory';
import config from './temp/config';
import componentFactory from './temp/componentFactory';
import VueFormulate from '@braid/vue-formulate'
import RacqSelectFormulateInput from './components/foundation/controls/RacqSelectFormulateInput';
import { createPinia, PiniaVuePlugin } from "pinia";
```

This is the server.bundle code where it is failing:

```
var useFormDataStore = Object(pinia["defineStore"])('formDataStore', {
  state: function state() {
    return {
      stepsData: []
    };
  },
  actions: {
    addStepData: function addStepData(stepNumber, stepData) {
      this.stepsData.push({
        stepNumber: stepNumber,
        data: stepData
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you compare your local and global node version, it both are different that may create a issue

Comment: @RishirajShekhawat I am using same node version on server and local.